# Read JavaScript variables live from website

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a question : A website is using JavaScript I can easily see the website scripts and it's script variables since it's on the client side.
My question is can I access those variables from c# and read their values live from the website ?
Help would be appreciated .

Comment: Do you want to extract information from existing Web page? If yes... The you'll need to write a crawler in c#... If this is what you want- I'll show you a simple way to get this done with a c# windows appand browser control.

Comment: Yes exactly from an existing website

Comment: You could take a look at [Javascriptdotnet](https://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

Create a window form app,add a Webbrowser control and then open required url in the browser. Once it gets loaded you can you something like this to access variables and stuff.

```
Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "variableName" });
```

I'm on the move so not able to type much

Hope this helps.